# Running into below at informatica error when running informatica jobs. AT salesforce end login history shows success

Tags: etl, informatica

```
Error - Severity    Timestamp   Node    Thread  Message Code    Message
ERROR   7/1/2020 7:20:23 PM node02_xxxxx READER_2_1_1   JAVA PLUGIN_1762    [ERROR] com.informatica.powercenter.sdk.SDKException: com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.connection.ConnectionFailedException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable"
    at com.informatica.cloud.adapter.sfdc.connection.SFDCConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.informatica.cloud.adapter.sfdc.lw.connection.SFDCConnectionLW.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.reader.runtime.GenericRdrPartitionDriver.init(Unknown Source)
```

I have used the SOAP version 33.0,42.0,45.0

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an issue with [proxy server information](https://kb.informatica.com/solution/23/Pages/65/525477.aspx).

You need to [configure HTTP Proxy Options for the PowerCenter Client](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powerexchange-adapters-for-powercenter/10-2-hotfix-2/powerexchange-for-snowflake-user-guide-for-powercenter/powerexchange-for-snowflake-configuration/configuring-http-proxy-options/configuring-http-proxy-options-for-the-powercenter-client.html).

Comment: I have verified the proxy settings and they  are good. And I ran curl command to connect salesforce uel from informatica unix server

Command - curl -v --user <salesforceuser>:<salesfrcepasswd> https://www.salesforce.com

Comment: Error on the UNIX server when i ran above command:

Error on unix server :
* About to connect() to www.salesforce.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 136.147.41.2...
* Connected to www.salesforce.com (136.147.41.2) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* NSS error -12263 (SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG)
* SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.